# SSL certificate generated by Firebase Hosting does not include connected domain

Tags: ssl, dns, firebase-hosting

We've had this issue twice during the last week. For a Firebase Hosting project with two connected domains, one domain is not included in the certificate.

Trying to connect with a browser seems to return a 503 status code and Chrome shows `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` in the console. `curl` returns

> (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '{host}'

(where `{host}` is the host name / connected domain)

To check the certificate directly, i.e. the [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name)s, I use the following command:

```
gnutls-cli --print-cert ${host} < /dev/null \
    | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' \
    | openssl x509 -noout -text \
    | grep DNS | tr , '\n' | tr -s " "
```

This returns a list of 100 certificates including the host name for the working domain, but only the default firebaseapp.com/*.firebaseapp.com entries for the failing domain.

*Note: I am using `gnutls-cli` here, because it seems that `openssl s_client -connect ${host}:443` does not include the host name in the request and always loads a certificate for firebaseapp.com/*.firebaseapp.com*

I have already reached out to Firebase Support, but their last response (~16 hours ago) was "there are two different domains associated to the same project, but I need to confirm if this is supported". I am quite sure this is supported, given that during my analysis of the problem I have found more than 400 SANs for the same two host names next to the domains under our responsibility.

Any suggestions on how we can resolve this issue? I already tried deleting and re-adding the custom domain, but this did not change anything.

Switching hosting would technically not be too difficult, but our main issue is that the DNS is under control of a service provider of our customer and it's difficult for them to change anything already in production.

Comment: It's been more than 3 days now that we have this problem and about 70 hours that we have raised this issue with Firebase support. Except for the response questioning whether our setup is supported, there has been no update from Firebase support on the ticket. I asked multiple times for confirmation from their side and when I created a new ticket it was immediately set to resolved with reference to the unresponsive ticket.

Any help or advice highly appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue, what I did is redirect with a CNAME record to the domain that firebase allow for the SSL certificate. It's not the best solution but user will not have the SSL Certificate message

Comment: @Pintouch Thank you for the suggestion. Do you mean, if x.com runs on Firebase Hosting and works, and y.com is the domain with the error above, I should to a CNAME on y.com to point to x.com? I think this would not resolve the problem with the correct SAN missing in the certificate, or am I missing something here?

Comment: No you're right, I checked what I did and I'm redirecting programmatically to the other domain. I remember to have try, but you're right with the missing name in SAN list you can't do that because it's the browser URL that is used for the SSL certificate... Any news from firebase?

Comment: @Pintouch Ok, good to know. I thought I misunderstood something. Too bad, but thank you for the update!

No news from Firebase Support: 3 days in they apologized for their delay and said they have "relied the provided information to [their] engineers" and another 5 days later they suggested I check the google-site-verification TXT records for another connected domain that's working. Done that, but no change. Not sure whether they are just guessing, or actually know what they're doing. They still don't have a solution nor a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some back and forth with Firebase Support, they found out that the root domain contained a [CAA record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization) that did not include *letsencrypt.org*.

The fix in our specific case was to include let's encrypt for the subdomain only. As an example, using the following settings

- Domain: `awesomesite.com`
- Connected Domain: `firebaseapp.awesomesite.com`

We can query the records using dig:

```
$ dig CAA awesomesite.com +noall +answer && dig CAA firebaseapp.awesomesite.com +noall +answer             

; <<>> (...) <<>> CAA awesomesite.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
awesomesite.com.        299 IN  CAA 0 iodef "mailto:cert@awesomesite.com"
awesomesite.com.        299 IN  CAA 0 issue "digicert.com"

; <<>> (...) <<>> CAA firebaseapp.awesomesite.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
firebaseapp.awesomesite.com.    3599    IN  CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
```

As you can see, the domain `firebaseapp.awesomesite.com` has a CAA record with *letsencrypt.org*, while `awesomesite.com` was not touched.

Everything works fine now, just a short time after updating the records. We did not have to retrigger deployment on Firebase Hosting or delete/add the connected domain (things I had previously tried to resolved the problem).

Alternatives to correct the issue:

- **Delete CAA records**: Remove the CAA record from the root domain (or intermediary domains).
- **Extend CAA records**: Include *letsencrypt.org* in the list of domains in the CAA record of the root domain

---

*Update, September 2020*: According to an email I have received, Google is in the process of migrating the SSL certificate provider to a new Google-run CA because of [Let's Encrypt's transition to ISRG's Root](https://letsencrypt.org/2019/04/15/transitioning-to-isrg-root.html) that may break backwards compatibility. According to that email, an additional CAA using `pki.goog` is required:

```
firebaseapp.awesomesite.com.    3599    IN  CAA 0 issue "pki.goog"
firebaseapp.awesomesite.com.    3599    IN  CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
```

Comment: This is a very good comment. Firebase support also needed days to come up with the same solution, so I expect this not the happen much. But they asked me to remove ALL other CAA records. I read now that this is not needed?

Comment: @Riël We have multiple CAAs on a single domain and on different levels in the hierarchy. and there is no issue. According to the spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8659#name-syntax), it should be no problem: "An FQDN MAY have multiple CAA RRs associated with it". If you have a day or so, you can try out, if it works with multiple CAAs (I assume it works :) )

Comment: Official firebase support response:
"Unfortunately it is necessary that only the two CAA records mentioned in my previous message are present in the DNS configuration of your domain and no other, if there are any other records the SSL certificate cannot be provisioned. It is also not possible to provision a certificate hosted by you so the only solution here is to remove the records or use a different domain.

I know it's not the answer you expected, however there is no workaround for this problem."

Maybe it is not possible to provision new certificates?

Comment: In our case, it is enterprise and the company is not allowed to add more CAA. This means we cannot use firebase anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

For your custom domain, if your DNS records have A records or CNAME records that point to other providers, Firebase is unable to provision an SSL certificate.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137747?hl=en

Comment: This is not the case here. As I had described, the certificate had been provisioned correctly, but then the process failed.